# How to change time format in Skype

Tags: skype, fedora-13

I would like the time to be displayed in AM/PM format, not the 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

1. enter the 'CONTROL PANEL' -> 'DATE TIME LANGUAGE AND REGIONAL OPTION'
2. Select 'regioanal & language'
3. select costumize
4. to turn it into a 12-hour format.
   enter the letter h (h small) in the time format.
   24-hour format if you want to enter the letter H

[image]